# fscanf troubles after opening file in C

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that opens a file and reads and stores the data.

The layout of the datafile appears as name;id#;score;number

i.e Bobby Ray Reynolds;111;10%;1

How do I store these fields in different variables.
This is what I'm trying:

```
    fscanf(fp, "%s %d %d %d", name,id,score,number);
```

Comment: If you want to write code that reads in a line of data and parses it, start with code that reads in a line of data. Then write code to parse that line.

Comment: Have you tried? fscanf(fp, "%s;%d;%d%%;%d", name,id,score,number);

Answer (score 4):

The problem with `fscanf`'s `%s` format specifier is that it stops as soon as it reaches a space. Given your format, this is incorrect: you are looking for a read of data up to a semicolon.

This can be achieved with `%[^;]` format. The complete format string would also use semicolons as separators between `%d` specifiers to match your file's format, like this:

```
fscanf(fp, "%32[^;];%d;%d%%;%d", name, id, score, number);
```

Note `32` above. This limit should correspond to the longest name that you would like to read. If `name` is an array of `N` characters, use `N-1` for the value between `%` and `[^;]` to avoid buffer overruns. Also note the `%%` after the second `%d`. That is required to match the percentage sign (second `%` is required by `fscanf`'s rules).